# Error in read_token ... not compatible with STRSXP with read_delim

Tags: r, parsing, readr

I'm trying to import the following text file (copied and pasted directly here) with `readr`'s `read_delim`:

```
sht_name    lon lat country
AD  42,546245   1,601554    Andorra
AE  23,424076   53,847818   United Arab Emirates
AF  33,93911    67,709953   Afghanistan
AG  17,060816   -61,796428  Antigua and Barbuda
AI  18,220554   -63,068615  Anguilla
AL  41,153332   20,168331   Albania
AM  40,069099   45,038189   Armenia
AN  12,226079   -69,060087  Netherlands Antilles
```

This is my code:

```
library(readr)
loc <- locale(decimal_mark = ",")
country_coordinates <- read_delim(file = 'list.txt', delim = '\t', col_names = TRUE,
                                  col_types = cols(sht_name = col_character(),
                                      lon = col_number(),
                                      lat = col_number(),
                                      country = col_character()),
                                  locale = loc)
```

This is my error:

```
Error in read_tokens_(data, tokenizer, col_specs, col_names, locale_,  : 
  not compatible with STRSXP
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Duplicated column names deduplicated: '' => '_1' [3], '' => '_2' [4] 
2: The following named parsers don't match the column names: sht_name, lon, lat, country
```

I've been struggling with this for far too long, can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

**edit:**

As an aside, if i import the info in csv form, with the below (very similar) code I have no issues:

```
country_coordinates <- read_csv2(file = 'list.csv', col_names = TRUE,
                                  col_types = cols(sht_name = col_character(),
                                                   lon = col_number(),
                                                   lat = col_number(),
                                                   country = col_character()),
                                  locale = loc)
```

Comment: `read_csv2()` uses `";"` for separators, instead of `","`

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero ";" is the separator, "," is the decimal mark.

Answer (score 0):

I might have some insight for you.

it seems that type_convert only takes character columns as input. I am guessing that your input columns are not class character.

So, in the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)  

bla   <- c('bill','bob','bill')
bling <- c(1,2,3)
bloop <- c("2015-05-05 13:23:00","2015-02-07 21:22:14","2015-01-01 17:30:15")
df <- tibble(bla, 
             bling, 
             bloop
             )
df_coltypes <- cols('bla'   = readr::col_factor(NULL) ,
                    'bling' = readr::col_integer()    ,
                    'bloop' = readr::col_datetime(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")    
                    )
df2 <- type_convert(df,trim_ws=TRUE,col_types = df_coltypes )
```

I get:

> Warning message: The following named parsers don't match the column names: bling

But if i do this:

```
df$bling <- as.character(df$bling)
df3 <- type_convert(df,trim_ws=TRUE,col_types = df_coltypes )
```

Then all of my columns convert.

Hope that helps.